# Join 2 DataFrame based on lookup within a Column of collections - Spark,Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, left-join

I have 2 dataframes as below,

```
val x = Seq((Seq(4,5),"XXX"),(Seq(7),"XYX")).toDF("X","NAME")

val y = Seq((5)).toDF("Y")
```

I want to join the two dataframes by looking up the value from `y` and searching the Seq/Array in `x.select("X")` if exists then join the complete Row with y

How can I acheive this is Spark?

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Spark 2.4.3 you could use higher-order function spark

```
scala> val x = Seq((Seq(4,5),"XXX"),(Seq(7),"XYX")).toDF("X","NAME")
scala> val y = Seq((5)).toDF("Y")

scala> x.join(y,expr("array_contains(X, y)"),"left").show
+------+----+----+
|     X|NAME|   Y|
+------+----+----+
|[4, 5]| XXX|   5|
|   [7]| XYX|null|
+------+----+----+
```

please confirm that's what you want to achieve?

Comment: @mani_nz is this what you want to achieve if yes then please accept the answer otherwise let me know what is your desired output

Comment: +1 for the solution. My application is on 2.4.0 and it fails. Is there a way to do this in another way for it to work in 2.4.0? Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

You can use an UDF for the join, works for all spark versions:

```
val array_contains = udf((arr:Seq[Int],element:Int) => arr.contains(element))

x
 .join(y, array_contains($"X",$"Y"),"left")
 .show()
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach you can use is to `explode` your array into rows with the new temporary column. If you run the following code:

```
x.withColumn("temp", explode('X)).show()
```

it would show:

```
+------+----+----+
|     X|NAME|temp|
+------+----+----+
|[4, 5]| XXX|   4|
|[4, 5]| XXX|   5|
|   [7]| XYX|   7|
+------+----+----+
```

As you can see you can now just do join using `temp` and `Y` columns (and then drop `temp`):

```
x.withColumn("temp", explode('X))
  .join(y, 'temp === 'Y)
  .drop('temp)
```

This may fail by creating duplicate rows if `X` contains duplicates. In this case, you'd have to additionally call `distinct`:

```
x.withColumn("temp", explode('X))
  .distinct()
  .join(y, 'temp === 'Y, "left")
  .drop('temp)
```

Since this approach is using spark native methods it [will be a little bit faster](https://medium.com/@Farox2q/udfs-vs-map-vs-custom-spark-native-functions-91ab2c154b44) than one using UDF, but arguably is less elegant.

Comment: Thanks! but udf is elegant for my my use case and it's not a lot of data which would need perf improvements so I'm going with @Raphael Roth answer! Appreciate your help!